# how to display specific menu list on device screen

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to create a responsive email navigation menu where menu list will shows but not included the Shop e-conolight on desktop screen but then on the mobile devices it will only display Shop e-conolight and Sale.

```
<li><a class="non-mobile" title="" href="#">LED Lightning</a></li>
<li ><a class="non-mobile" title="" href="#">Linear Fluorescent</a></li>
<li><a class="non-mobile" title="" href="#">Wall Packs</a></li>
<li><a class="non-mobile" title="" href="#">Floodlights</a></li>
<li><a class="non-mobile" title="" href="#">Exit &amp; Emergency</a></li>
<li ><a class="show-mobile" title="" href="#">Shop e-conolight</a></li>
<li class="active"><a title="" href="#" class="sale" style="color:#fff;">Sale</a></li>

@media only screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (min-device-width:480px) and (max-width: 600px) {
      .non-mobile { display: none; }
      .show-mobile{
            display:inline-block;
      } 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 3024px) {
      .show-mobile{ display: none; }
}
```

[image: This is what I would like it to look like]

Comment: Is there something in particular that doesn't work the way you're expecting?  http://cssdeck.com/labs/aryheimg.  Is there a particular reason you believe that mobile users are not interested in purchasing Floodlights, LED Lightning (sic), or any of those other items?

Comment: Hi Cimmanon, The reason being why we concise our menu on mobile devices is because if we show all of them it will too small or it will display on the second line which doesn't look and then we don't want to use the dropdown menu. Thank you!

Comment: But you do understand that mobile users don't like useful content taken away from them, right?

Comment: Yes, I do but our marketing department really wanted to have this look I'm not sure if this will have a great bounce or not but I'm hoping with your help I am able to produce this menu in two different look. Thanks, Cimmanon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media(min-width:601px)
{
  .show-mobile{display:none;}
  .non-mobile{display:inline-block;}
}

@media(max-width:600px)
{
  .show-mobile{display:inline-block;}
  .non-mobile{display:none;
}
.sale{display:inline-block}
```

This will hide the non-mobile ones when the screen width goes down to less than 600px and will hide the mobile only ones when the screen is larger than 600px.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmRUw/) of it.

You may want to change the non-mobile and show-mobile classes to the `li` elements to hide the actual element not just the `a` tag inside.

edit: here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmRUw/1/) of that.